# Getting errors in php from retrieving data from mysql database in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

So I am trying to retrieve data from MySQL database (myphpadmin) using laravel framework. I want to make a search engine that can search my data in the database, for your information I am retrieving the data from myphpadmin using xampp. Basically, I want to display the data that I will be searching for in the UI. For example, student id is = 1000, when I search 1000 it should display me with the student information.

This is my code:
Controller:

[image: Controller image]

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
class PredictionController extends Controller
{
    public function predictionData(){

       $datas = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT id, sex, reason, failures, higher,absences, G1,G2,G3 from real_test;"));
       return view('predictionPage', ['datas' =>$datas]);
    }
    public function search(){
        $search_student = $_GET['search'];
        $datas = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT id, sex, reason, failures, higher,absences, G1,G2,G3 from real_test;"));
        $data = $datas::where('id','LIKE','%' .$search_student. '%')->get();
        return view('adminLayout.predictionPage', ['data' => $data]);
    }
}
```

This is my code for HTML display :

[image: HTML blade code]

I tried many things. one time I got an array to string error. Another time I got that foreach cannot identify the data (I searched about it and people say its because you do not have an array for that, but I saw one website he did the same thing as me but it displayed for him, the only difference is that he is using data from his database section).
This is my error: Class name must be a valid object or a string, and it's pointing towards $data = $datas::where ... line.

Please help, I have been trying and searching for 3 hours

This is my error Right now :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCtbF.png

Comment: Looking at the Laravel document, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#select-statements, the select method is only meant to take in column names.

Comment: First, remove the semi-colon from your DB::raw statement, it's not necessary and might be breaking your query. Though you don't need that as a raw at all since you're not doing anything odd with it. `DB::table('real_test')->select(['id','sex','reason','failures','higher', 'absences','G1','G2','G3'])` is fine. What is the exact error that you're getting right now with this code?

Comment: Please post the specific error you are receiving.

Comment: Please go read [ask], among other things it explains how a halfway proper question title should be phrased.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Which of these lines in your code cause that error?

Comment: _NOTE_ `phpMyAdmin is not a database its a tool written in PHP. your database appears to be MySQL

Comment: i posted the error.

Comment: @nico haase, i tried many ways to resolve this error, as I said i got multiple errors, like the conversion from array to string error. The cause of the error, is the line at $data = $datas, and the error is Class name must be a valid object or a string.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using `$_GET` instead of `request()->get('search');` But between those two lines, try `Log::info('Type of datas is '.gettype($datas));` and check your log in `storage/logs` to see what the type is.

Comment: i fixed the issue, thank you @aynber from your code db::table I made up a solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First i have to thank @aynber because of his code I came up with a solution.

So what I did is use @aynber code

```
$data = DB::table('real_test')->select(['id','sex','reason','failures','higher', 'absences','G1','G2','G3'])->where('id','LIKE','%' .$search_student. '%')->get();
```

and instead of having another `$data` I just put an arrow `->` and added where to the search, and the answer came up to me.

Thank you aynber you have no idea how much I have tried.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).